# Let $G$ be a finite simple group. Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with index $n=|G:H|>1$. Show that $|H|$ divides $(n-1)!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group. Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with index $n=|G:H|>1$. Show that $|H|$ divides $(n-1)!$ Hint: consider the action of $G$ on right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

I'm not sure I even know where a starting point would be.
Thanks

Comment: Show that there is a non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $S_n$. What can you say about the kernel of that using the assumption that $G$ is simple?

Comment: The hint gives you a starting point. Follow the hint.

Answer (score 2):

The action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ gives a homomorphism $G\to S_n$.  This must be injective, else the kernel would be a normal subgroup of $G$.

Now we have $n|H|=|G|$ and $|G|$ divides the order of $S_n\ldots$

Comment: could you explain a little more about why the kernel would be a normal subgroup, thanks

Comment: kernel is always normal, what he wants to say is if action is not injective then kernel will not be trivial and then kernel will be a proper normal subgroup of  G . but that cant hold since G is Simple. Action is injective so kernel is trivial, i.e {e}

Comment: okay, so where does $n|H|$ come from?

Comment: $G/ker(G\rightarrow S_n)=G \hookrightarrow S_n$. And $|G|=n|H|$.

Comment: @user150068: Since the index of $H$ in $G$ is $n$, we have $|G|=n|H|$.